# talend data insertion with auto increment keys

Tags: etl, auto-increment, talend

I am using talend studio free version. I have an excel with 2 sheets "System" and "Part" table data. I want to insert the data into redshift tables system and part respectively. First I want to check if given system is already present in redshift table, if yes, retrieve its system id, if not then add it with new system id. The same goes for part data, if part already present, get the part id, if not then add the record with new id.

Once this is done, the system id(existing/new) along with part id(existing/new) should be added to a map table system_to_part which has columns system_id and part_id.

The tables in redshift are created with ids as auto increment and upon adding rows I see ids generated. But how can I take the ids in talend and insert into a new table(system_to_part)?

Comment: If your intention is to merge the data finally into system_to_part table from system and part table, why not leverage `Redshift` merge to insert/update the data and not follow what/how to retrieve the ids from `Talend`.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I dont want to insert the whole system and part table data in system_to_part table, but only the auto incremented ids for mapping. And it will work on scheduled basis so only newly added records should be considered. And if I am mistaken, could you please elaborate the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: what I meant was to leverage the `Redshift` options that we have instead of `Talend`. Let me try to explain it here - 1. have a temp table which will hold the data from system/part table - you can consider to have all the columns or only the id columns. 2. Now use the temp table to insert the records into system_to_part table which doesn't exist (`INSERT INTO system_to_part
SELECT * FROM temp_system_to_part temp
WHERE temp.primary_key NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT primary_key FROM system_to_part)`)